# How to use `blockchain.scripthash.subscribe` from a tcp socket in Electrum server

Tags: json-rpc, electrum, tcp, electrum-server

As a personal exercise I want to write a minimal copy of BTCPayServer. I decided to use Electrum server instead of a node to fetch information from the network. My final goal is to be able to track the transactions received by an address, but so far I'm stuck. I was able to use `blockchain.scripthash.get_balance` after some work, but now I'm having issues with `blockchain.scripthash.subscribe`. There are 2 things that confuse me:

1. This method is supposed to establish a subscription and return a notification every time the scripthash changes, as explained [here](https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-methods.html#blockchain-scripthash-subscribe). How are these notifications returned? If I keep the tcp socket open for too long, the connection is eventually closed. When I read the [jsonrpc spec](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#notification), notifications are more akin to something the client sends to the server, not the other way around.
2. How can I decode the returned status? I've read the [electrumx's docs](https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-basics.html#status), but I'm not sure how to reverse this last step

> 4. The status of the script hash is the sha256() hash of the full string expressed as a hexadecimal string, or null if the string is empty because there are no transactions.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone has any experience, or can point me to some code/articles that explain in detail how to properly integrate electrum.